# How to avoid that return key gives me back on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio

I am programming on Android Studio. I use different intents, but, when I press "return key", on my phone, I come back to the last intent. I would like to avoid it. I want, that if your press "return key", the app just finishes. How can I do it? Maybe, erasing the intent historial?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can overwrite the on back method:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
}
```

this should do the trick.